# File won't upload to ftp server

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file from my webserver to my game server through a script. The problem is that it can't find the directory.

The full directory is /174.34.132.106 port 27015/tf/addons/sourcemod/configs/tf2items.weapons.txt

This path didn't work so I asked the hosting about it and they insisted that /tf/addons/sourcemod/configs/tf2items.weapons.txt is the correct path but this doesn't work either. The game server is running on a windows server and i'm pretty sure the web server is running on linux. Is my code wrong, do I have to replace the spaces in the directory with %20. Thanks in advance!

```
    $ftp_server="174.34.132.106";
$ftp_user_name="Username";
$ftp_user_pass="Password";
    $remote_file = "tf2items.weapons.txt";
$file = "weapons/tf2items.weapons.txt";//tobe uploaded 
if(!file_exists($file)) echo "The local file does not exist";


 $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die('Unable to create the connection');

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

ftp_chdir($conn_id, "174.34.132.106 port 27015/tf/addons/sourcemod/configs/");
echo ftp_pwd($conn_id);

if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) { 
   echo "successfully uploaded $file\n"; 
   exit; 
} else { 
  echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n"; 
  exit; 
  } 

 // close the connection 
  ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: If you're ever not sure about the directories, just log in with a regular FTP client and see if you can navigate it and copy the exact directory format into your script.

Comment: Which part didn't work? Navigating to the directory in the FTP program, or using the copied directory into your script? If you can't navigate to the directory, and you can't drill down through the folders from the directory you start in, then you need to talk to the host again.

Comment: Using the copied directory, i'll talk to the host again and see what they have to say.

Comment: Would I need to do anything different to the script if its Uploading from a linux FTP server to a Windows FTP server?

Comment: No, but I did just notice something with the port. I'll create it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the FTP server you're connecting to is using a non-standard port, so it's probably not making the connection. You need to specify the port in the ftp_connect, like so:

```
$ftp_server="174.34.132.106";
$ftp_port = "27015";
$ftp_user_name="username";
$ftp_user_pass="password";
$remote_file = "tf/addons/sourcemod/configs/tf2items.weapons.txt";
$file = "weapons/tf2items.weapons.txt";//tobe uploaded 


// set up basic connection 
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,$ftp_port) or die('Unable to create the connection');
```

The die() will stop the script if it's unable to make the connection. You can add the same after your ftp_login line to make sure that it's actually logging in.

**Edit** To make sure your file exists, try this above the ftp_put line.

```
if(!file_exists($file)) echo "The local file does not exist";
```

**Edit 2** After reading down on [ftp_put](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php), it says that the remote_file does not support directories. You'll need to use [ftp_chdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php) first.

```
ftp_chdir($conn_id, "tf/addons/sourcemod/configs/");
```

Then for remote_file, use just `tf2items.weapons.txt`. You can still use filepaths for the local file.

Comment: Adding the port still didn't upload the file. Incase this can help heres the error it's displaying.                                             Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: The system cannot find the file specified. in /chroot/home/august5t/august5th.org/html/admin/pages/assets/viewweapons.php on line 230
There was a problem while uploading weapons/tf2items.weapons.txt Also it is finding the local file I already checked that.

Comment: It sounds like it can't find your local file. I updated the answer with some code to try to make sure the script is seeing your local file.

Comment: The port that you have is the port that the game server runs on not the ftp. I changed it back to the original port which is 21 and it still can't find the file on the web server. It however can find the file on the local server. It is also connecting to the ftp.

Comment: I updated the answer. ftp_put does not support paths for the remote file. You need to change the remote directory before you can upload the file.

Comment: I updated my new code but i'm still getting "Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: The system cannot find the file specified." It is finding the directory though, "/174.34.132.106 port 27015/tf/addons/sourcemod/configs" works! For some reason I still can't upload the file though.

Comment: Also using /174.34.132.106 port 27015/tf/addons/sourcemod/configs isntead of tf/addons/sourcemod/configs/tf2items.weapons.txt doesn't matter apparently, they both find the directory.

Comment: It is creating the new file it just cant copy the data from the file in the webserver to the gameserver.

Comment: Alright it turns out I had to put it in passive mode [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php)[/link]

Answer (score 0):

If that's a Linux server ensure that you use correct case for directory names.

"tf/addons/sourcemod/configs" is not the same as "TF/addons/sourcemod/configs";